# What it means for something to be twice as hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, scales

Can the statement "the sun is $1000$ times hotter than the Earth" make sense without a scale system. I often hear such statements but does it only make sense when using a system with $0$ as absolute zero such as kelvin? For example, $\mathrm{20^\circ C}$ is twice as hot as $10$ degrees but the equivalent $68$ Fahrenheit is not twice as much as $50$ Fahrenheit. Furthermore, $\mathrm{1^\circ C}$ is not infinitely times hotter than $0$. How can we define something to be "X times as hot"? And in general, how can this be generalized to other systems. It seems like only a scale with $0$ being set as the absolute minimum can qualify such statements.

Comment: *$\mathrm{20^\circ C}$ is twice as hot as $10$ degrees* That’s not true. (But I didn’t downvote.)

Answer (score 2):

Let’s take length for example. It makes intuitive sense to say that this stick is twice as long as that stick without bothering to go into scales. This statement is scale independent. Why is that? Well that’s because if we were to measure it using some scale, we fix the origin to one end of the stick and measure the length of the other end from there.

So it makes sense because we’re inherently measuring length differences. This is possible because the origin is fixed. Similarly, if the temperature scale had an unambiguous origin, then we’d always be talking about temperature difference (wrt that origin) and then the statement twice as hot would make sense.

Well luckily there does exist an unambiguous origin and that’s $0K$! So for a statement of twice as hot to make physical sense, it has to be a statement consistent with the Kelvin scale.